# Getting registry keys of Managed objects from SNMP

Tags: c#, snmp

I am using SNMP to get system related information in windows. I am able to get installed software details.I am using net-snmp c# library commands(snmpwalk,snmpgetnext). But it is not returning software version, Publisher name.How i will be able to get extra details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I can see that you are trying to query information from Windows SNMP service.

Unfortunately that Microsoft thinks WMI is more suitable for its products, so its SNMP implementation is too simple to provide you all the information you need. You either need to switch to WMI, or have to extend its SNMP agent (via custom modules).

Therefore, if you are seriously deciding to develop an application for your requirements, consider WMI as the preferred approach, not SNMP.